# How to evaluate the value of an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(2^{-2k}+2^{1-2k}-2^{-2k-2}-2^{-2k-1}-\frac{1}{6}\times\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^k\right)$$ . Any ideas here ?

Comment: What's more important is where're your own thoughts? Motivate us to answer your question. What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough details . I tried factoring to see if I can get a nicer form and maybe some cancellation , but got to to something useless.

Comment: I'll break it into partial sums , use geometric progressions , then reconstruct it and take the limit . I was curious if anyone could come up with an iteresting approach

Comment: Since each of the individual terms form a geometric series, just apply the formula $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$ to them and you'll get the result. Of course look for the constant multiplication terms.

Comment: That's what I did as well , thanks for your answer ! :D

Comment: Hint: $$2^{-2k}+2^{1-2k}-2^{-2k-2}-2^{-2k-1} = \frac{9}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$2^{-2k}=\frac{1}{2^{2k}}$$
and
$$2^{1-2k}=\frac{2}{2^{2k}}$$
$$-2^{-2-2k}=-\frac{1}{2*2*2^{2k}}$$
$$-2^{-1-2k}=-\frac{1}{2*2^{2k}}$$
so we can rewrite the sum as
$$2^{-2k}+2^{1-2k}-2^{-2-2k}-2^{-1-2k}=\frac{3}{2^{2k}}-\frac{3}{2*2*2^{2k}}=\frac{9}{4*2^{2k}}=\frac{9}{4}*(\frac{1}{2})^{2k}$$
now lets rewrite the sum as  two separate sums
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{9}{4}*(\frac{1}{2})^{2k} - \frac{1}{6}*(\frac{5}{6})^k= \frac{9}{4}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{4})^{k}\right) - \frac{1}{6}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{5}{6})^{k}\right)$$
Now by using the sum of infinite geometric series 
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}$$
(for all $|r|<1$)

we gain
$$\frac{9}{4}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{4})^{k}\right) - \frac{1}{6}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{5}{6})^{k}\right)=\frac{9}{4}*\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{6}*\frac{6}{1}=2$$
which is the answer to your original question.